# Iterate a list of web elements and obtain two or more values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to iterate to the list of web elements to get the text of the name and title

example:

```
<ul id="GalleryViewInner" class="gv-ic">
<li id="item3ad73f1239" class="sresult gvresult">
    <div id="1"
        <span id="span1">5,000USD</span>
    </div>  
    <div id="2"
        <td id="td1">TITLE</td>
    </div>
<li id="item3ad73f1239" class="sresult gvresult">
<li id="item3ad73f1239" class="sresult gvresult">
<li id="item3ad73f1239" class="sresult gvresult">
<li id="item3ad73f1239" class="sresult gvresult">
</ul>
```

iterate ul list:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='GalleryViewInner']/li"));

    Iterator<WebElement> iter = allElements.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        WebElement PRICE = iter.next();

        PRICE.getTxt();
        TITLE.getText();

        }
```

in each iteration I need to get two or more elements from each "li"

***I need to get price and name of all the li elements***

Java

Selenium Webdriver

Comment: can you share the actual URL?

Comment: Try just using a css selector `#GalleryViewInner li`

Comment: The HTML you have posted is not valid. You also mention you need name and title but there's no reference to name anywhere in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Asumming your web elements like you showed us above, and other `<li></li>` are the same

```
<ul id="GalleryViewInner" class="gv-ic">
<li id="item3ad73f1239" class="sresult gvresult">
    <div id="1"
        <span id="span1">5,000USD</span>
    </div>  
    <div id="2"
        <td id="td1">TITLE</td>
    </div>
</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Asumming price is `<span></span>` with id "span1" and name is `<td></td>` with id "td1" I'll go with this approach

```
List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='GalleryViewInner']/li"));
for(WebElement li : liElements){
    WebElement spanPrice = li.findElement(By.id("span1"));
    String price = spanPrice.getText();
    WebElement tdName = li.findElement(By.id("td1"));
    String name = tdName.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have provided to get the text of the `name` and `title` you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> all_span_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='GalleryViewInner']//li/div/span"));
List<WebElement> all_td_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='GalleryViewInner']//li//following::div[2]/td"));
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement ele1:all_span_elements)
    names.add(ele1.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for(WebElement ele2:all_td_elements)
    titles.add(ele2.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for(int i=0; i<all_span_elements.size(); i++)
    System.out.println("Medicine Name is : " + names.get(i) + "and Title is : " + titles.get(i));
```